# .htaccess redirect or rewrite from one pdf to another

Tags: .htaccess, pdf, redirect, url-rewriting

I am not sure of the correct way to redirect or rewrite in .htaccess when one .pdf is requested.. to give them another one.

Requirement:  I need to it to also show the correct (new) .pdf name in the url/address as well..

right now.. I believe I am getting the new .pdf content.. but the URL is the same as the old/original .pdf name..

examples I have tried:

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^aa/bb/cc/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018.pdf
#RewriteRule ^(.*) /aa/bb/cc/Volume10-Issue3-Summer2018.pdf [NC,R=302,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^aa/bb/cc/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018.pdf http://domainame.org/aa/bb/cc/Volume10-Issue3-Summer2018.pdf [NC,R=302,L]
```

*These pdf are on the same domain (same directory actually as well)

Do I need to do a REDIRECT to get the new url/file name in the url (address)?

update:  These attempts are NOT working:

## attempt 1

`RewriteRule ^UserFiles/file/news/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018.pdf$ /UserFiles/file/news/Volume10-Issue3-Summer2018.pdf [L,NC,R=301`]

## attempt 2

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/UserFiles/file/news)/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018.pdf$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^ %1/Volume10-Issue3-Summer2018.pdf [R=302,L]
```

## attempt 3

```
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^UserFiles/file/news/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018.pdf
#RewriteRule ^(.*) /UserFiles/file/news/Volume10-Issue3-Summer2018.pdf [NC,R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your top rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/aa/bb/cc)/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018\.pdf$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/Volume10-Issue3-Summer2018.pdf [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Other rules may rewrite this URI to something else.

Comment: update: it is NOT redirecting.. I thought it had old name.. but its not redirecting at all (old/original .pdf content displayed!)

Comment: and to double check.. that %1 is correct?  should not be $1....right?  (neither worked to be clear.. but I wanted to ask)

Comment: The LINK (URL) stems from an HTML email being sent out (with a bad link in it to an old .pdf)

http://www.xxxx.com/UserFiles/file/news/Volume10-Issue2-Spring2018.pdf

I updated the original post with the 3 attempts I tried and failed with.

Yes.. this htaccess file has many entries in it.

Comment: Located in the root of the site (other rewrites seem to be working correctly) No other .htaccess files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180753/discussion-between-anubhava-and-whispers).

Comment: FYI...  answer was spot on.. but my order/placement was crucial.  TOP PLACEMENT must be adhered to when troubleshooting.